# Is there software that allows me to experiment with solar sail parameters?

Tags: software, solar-sail

Is there any software that allows me to experiment with solar sail models?

I want to try models of sails of different sizes, different positions around the Solar System, and different trajectories.

Answer (score 4):

Martin Schweiger's ["Orbiter"](http://orbit.medphys.ucl.ac.uk/download.html) (a freely downloadable simulation/game) has basic radiation pressure simulation and apparently a solar sail scenario which would be the first thing to try. (I haven't tried radiation pressure simulation at all though.)

For example see a vague mention of this ability [here](http://www.orbiter-forum.com/showthread.php?t=33480):

(Hint: if the solar sail doesn't have any attitude controls, point it coarsely using the Scenario Editor to alter pitch/roll/yaw, and kill any unwanted angular velocity if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

[The Union pour la Promotion de la Propulsion Photonique has a Java solar sail simulator](http://www.u3p.net/prop/simu/sjava_a.htm).

By default it starts with a circular orbit at 1 AU, and remains in that plane.  It is not quite what you are after, but does allow one to change orientation and lightness number.